# Querying an array within an array with Postgres JSONB query

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have some JSON in a field in my Postgres 9.4 db and I want to find rows where the given name is a certain value, where the field is named `model` and the JSON structure is as follows:

```
{
    "resourceType": "Person",
    "id": "8a7b72b1-49ec-43e5-bd21-bc62674d9875",
    "name": [
      {
        "family": [
          "NEWMAN"
        ],
        "given": [
          "JOHN"
        ]
      }
    ]
}
```

So I tried this: `SELECT * FROM current WHERE model->'name' @> '{"given":["JOHN"]}';` (as well as various other guesses) but that does not match the above data. How should I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the function [`jsonb_array_elements()`:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)

```
select t.*
from current t,
jsonb_array_elements(model->'name') names
where names->'given' ? 'JOHN'
```

Comment: I was excited, but: "cannot extract elements from an object".

Comment: This means that the actual json structure is different than that described in your question. The `name` object must be an array in every row. You can [test it here.](http://rextester.com/JDHIC62950)

Comment: Ah! I forgot to limit the query by resourceType. Thanks - it works.